# angularjs: set element's html from a template url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my directive, I'd like to set the html of the element based on a template url:

```
element.html('some url to a template html file');
```

instead of

```
element.html('<div>test</div>').show();
```

how can I do that ?

**EDIT**

I do not wish to use templateUrl because the template must be **dynamic**. The template will change according to a scope variable set on the directive. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear before.

Comment: How about using `templateUrl: url` in the directive

Comment: You should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: What do you mean by "the template must be dynamic" ?  Does that mean that you will have different html templates and you need to dynamically select which one to display, or that the actual HTML markup in the template will change based on some scope variable?

Comment: first scenario. I will have different html templates and based on a value passed to the directive, the template will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you really want to do this you will have to use the `$compile` service.
Maybe try to take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632332/1491850).

Comment: excellent. I was already using $compile, but the answer was to use $http and $templateCache. Thanks !