# Binding data in a custom directive - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a custom directive, and its purpose is to present a widget and bind it to a variable.
Every variable has different data type, so different widgets will be presented depending on the data type.

My problem is that I can pass the data of the variable, but I can't manage to bind the widget to it.

To simplify the problem, my widget is just a simple text input.
When I try to $compile the widget, Angular uses the value of the variable instead of binding to it.

HTML:

```html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="resource.name"></div>
  <div custom-widget widget-type="widget" bind-to="resource"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('customWidget', function($compile) {
    return {
      replace: true,
      template: '<div></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {

      },
      scope: {
        bindTo: "=bindTo",
        widgetType: "=widgetType"
      },
      link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
        var html = '<div>' + scope.widgetType.label + ':<input ng-bind="' + scope.bindTo[scope.widgetType.id] + '" /></div>';
        iElem.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.widget = {
      id: 'name',
      label: 'Text input',
      type: 'text'
    };
    $scope.resource = {
      name: 'John'
    };
  });
```

Plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/qhUdNhjSN7NlP4xRVcEA?p=preview

I'm still new to AngularJS and my approach may not be the best, so any different ideas are of course appreciated!

Comment: what do you want to achieve is not clear

Comment: in the Plunker demo, I want the 2 fields to be two-way-binded to $scope.resource.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an isolate scope one issue is that `resource` is on the parents scope and not visible within the directive.  And I think you're looking for `ng-model` rather than `ng-bind`.

Also, since you want to bind to `name`in `resource`, we need to tie that in somehow.

So here's one approach to your template html (note the addition of `$parent` to get around the scope issue and the addition of `.name`(which you could add programatically using a variable if you preferred, or specify it as part of the attribute))

```
var html = '<div>' + scope.widgetType.label + ':<input ng-model="' + '$parent.' + iAttrs.bindTo +'.name'+ '" /></div>';
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXXu7mWwH5ORl3K0j3QD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what $parent means? Does it just points to the parent scope of the current one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you have a isolated scope within your directive and use the "=" operator you already have two-way data binding.

My suggestion would be to use the "template" more like a view so the operations are clearer.

I would change your directive to the following:

Using ng-model instead of ng-bing mainly because as the [Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) reveals:

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive. [[...]](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel)

Changed directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('customWidget', function($compile) {
    return {
      replace: true,
      template: '<div> {{widgetType.label}} <input ng-model="bindTo[widgetType.id]" /></div>',
      scope: {
        bindTo: "=bindTo",
        widgetType: "=widgetType"
      }
   };
 });
```

EDIT:
Ops forgot the [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJk7u3h0hvTKtBuvYa21?p=preview)

Comment: It is a lot clearer, but my main goal is to have different custom widgets, depending on the type of the data. Is it possible to have different templates depending on widgetType.type?

Comment: @GuyB7 Hmm, got it. Well it is possible to change the template according to the type, but that would involve using $http and $compile in the linking function to get the url's of the different widget [(like this dude suggests)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632260/can-you-change-templateurl-on-the-fly), or maybe take a look at the [ngInclude directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude). Sorry if it didn't help much, best of luck! Cheers.