# How to add TemplateURL for a variable inside Directive Link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

How can I include a template URL inside link function in a directive? I am trying to do something like this:

```
app.directive('something', function($compile,$timeout) {

   return: {

      link: function(scope,element,attrs) {

           var htmlText = ???? // HOW TO INCLUDE A TEMPLATE URL HERE??

            $compile(htmlText)(scope, function(_element,_scope) {
         element.replaceWith(_element);                 
    });

      }, 

   }

});
```

When I searched, I understand that Angular directives can use `templateUrl`. But I am trying to store the html codes to a variable that is placed inside the `link` which in the end gets compiled. Usually for small codes, I just type the HTML inline to `var htmlText`. But if I have a lot of code, I want to save that to a separate html file and then call that for that variable (like its shown in example above). So my questions are

**1) How can I add a link to template URL for a variable inside `link`?**

**2) When I am adding the url path, do I add the relative path from where the index.html file is located or the path from where that directive file is located?**

Comment: I didn't quite understand why you can't use the `templateUrl` property? There used to be some problems with `transclude` and async fetching of templates but to my knowledge that's been resolved in newer versions.

Comment: From what I understand I dont think the templateURL property will work if the template depends on scope data.

Comment: Seems to work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9NCSytGVEc4tJaIGjnGv?p=preview but maybe there are issues if the directive's scope is not isolated?`I've never heard of that being a problem before though.

Comment: good example... yeah it seems to work well with isolated scope. But when I have it as `scope=false`, it wasnt working. I will look into this more and play around a bit.. thank you for showing this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a workaround you could just use `ng-include` in a normal `<div>` that you render with `$compile`, so something like:

```
link: function(scope,element,attrs) {

       var htmlText = '<div ng-include="path/to/template.html"></div>';

       $compile(htmlText)(scope, function(_element,_scope) {
       element.replaceWith(_element);                 
});
```

**[EDIT]**

There is even a nicer solution in [this Thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632260/can-you-change-templateurl-on-the-fly)
The Path depends on how your Webserver is configured. But usually yes, its the relative Path of your Index.html.

Comment: Thats perfect! The idea of using the `ng-include` method in a normal `<div>` is a good idea and simple too. I went with the solution in the thread you had given that uses `$http`  and `$templaceCache`. Thank you so much. Your answer helped me so much. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**$templateCache**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PnrM7/) is the code, that shows how it works:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <!-- Include template in $templateCache AUTOMATICALLY -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="auto.tpl.html">
        <span style="background-color:yellow">{{title}}</span>        
    </script>

    <dir tpl-id="auto.tpl.html" title="Automatic"></dir>
    <dir tpl-id="manual.tpl.html" title="Manual"></dir>
</body>
```

*script:*

```
angular.module('App',[])
.directive('dir',['$templateCache','$compile',function($templateCache,$compile){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:true,
        link:function($scope, iElement, attrs){
            //Include template in $templateCache MANUALLY
            $templateCache.put('manual.tpl.html','<span style="background-color:red">{{title}}</span>');
            //----------------------------            

            $scope.title = attrs['title'];
            $compile($templateCache.get(attrs['tplId']))($scope,function(cElement){
                iElement.replaceWith(cElement);                
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Engineer. I like your approach too. However it looks like a lot of work when compared to the other solution. Thank you heaps though. YOur answer gives me an idea on how I can do that using `$templateCache`.  Much obliged!