# AngularJS: Couldn't retrieve value from custom directive attribute to parse in custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**HTML**

```
<div my-test="{{widget.code}}"></div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
.directive('myTest', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl : function(elem, attr) {
            console.log(attr.myTest);
            return  attr.myTest+'-widget.html' || 'blank-widget.html';
        }
    };
})
```

I have this codes above and I am trying to retrieve the value under myTest which is the value that {{widget.code}} has. I also tried to search for solutions and possible workaround [1] [2] [3], and it seems I couldn't get through the problem.

console.log(attr.myTest) always tells me {{widget.code}} but if I try to see the source it will display  the value that I am needing. Can somebody point me to what solution I can do on this? Thank you!

[1] https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
[2] [Accessing attributes from an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913841/accessing-attributes-from-an-angularjs-directive)
[3] http://plnkr.co/edit/wWHZG97CviYrUxmxjSOb?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632260/can-you-change-templateurl-on-the-fly) which manages the templateUrl through the link phase.

Comment: I totally forgot that we are using templateUrl here. Will be back in a sec

Comment: Updated my answer, seems like this has been answered before.