# Change templateURL of directive dynamically after $http.get()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-templatecache

I'm working on 'skeleton' loading the UI in different components. I have a directive that I'm loading a template initially (this template has low opacity and looks like a mock table). Once I get the data I need in an `http.get()` then I want to change the `templateUrl` of the directive. Below is what I've tried so far.

```
function registers($log, $state, $templateCache, currentCountData, storeFactory) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/shared/tableMock/tableMock.html',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        storeFactory.getRegisters().then(function (data) {
            scope.registers = data.registers;
            $templateCache.put('/app/dashboard/registers/registers.html');
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I'm on the right track. I can step through and see the `storeFactory` return the correct data from my `factory`. How can I then change the `templateUrl` of the directive?

Comment: Why not just put the real template to begin with, but put an ng-if inside and start off showing your mock table, and once data is loaded set the variable that ng-if checks so it hides the mock and then shows the other.

Comment: that is sloppy, a lot of markup and business logic in one file.

Comment: Really? Adding one line <div ng-show="someval">my mock image</div> and <div ng-hide=""> to your template is sloppy?  Seriously?

Comment: As opposed to doing it the correct way and simply using CSS to have the real table appear in a "working" mode until data shows up and not having 2 templates that BLOAT your code.

Comment: Scott, we'll agree to disagree, you don't have all the facts. What I'm doing allows the "working" templates to be reused and modified for each situation. Not sure why you're so touchy about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632332/453985) question I was able to come up with this

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {                        
    storeFactory.getRegisters().then(function (data) {
        scope.registers = data.registers;
        $http.get('/app/dashboard/registers/registers.html', { cache: $templateCache }).success(function (tplContent) {
            element.replaceWith($compile(tplContent)(scope));
        });
    });
}
```

`tplContent` correlates to the response of the `$http.get()`. It's the html in the `registers.html` file. `element` represents the directive itself.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this I usually do something like this in my directive template:

```
<div ng-switch="viewState">
  <div ng-switch-when="gotRegisters">
   Content for when you get the registers
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
   For when you don't have the registers
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you could just change a variable to show your content `ie scope.viewState = 'gotRegisters';` instead of waiting for it to download after you already downloaded your registers.

Comment: This would certainly work. I decided to load the new template in dynamically. See my answer.